# Edittext in LinearLayout flickers in scrolling the background

Tags: android, background, android-edittext, android-linearlayout

I programmatically add views (Edittext) in a linearlayout. Actually is a form. But the problem is tha all this is in a Relative and the Relative in a scrollview. Whenever i scroll the bg of the linearlayout (form) flickers. I notice tha if i remove the focusable attribute from edittext it stops doing it, but i cannot press on the edittext.

How can i stop this flicker??

Comment: this answer solve the issue
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16981906/5561624
and i it works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i didnt solve it correctly but i mad a android-hack :)

The problem is related with the focus of the edittexts. I tried adding requestfocus or android:descendantFocusability to the linearLayout with no result.

So i made another LinearLayout with the required background, alignBottom with the actual form and the actual-form with no-background.

I am sure that the same flicker happens but there is no background so there is any visual problem.