# This is a Solution for "flickering issue on scrolling" on Android Device

Tags: android, flicker

You will see a flickering issue on edit text boxes when you try to scroll. This is an issue often seen and is due to bad coding while creating View using XML.
See the following samples on understanding the issue.

```
         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/stepText"
            android:background="@drawable/textbox_group_border"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/emailArea"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dip" 
                **android:background="@color/color_white"**
                >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="45dip"
                    **android:background="@color/color_white"**
                    android:hint="@string/email_address"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                    android:paddingRight="55dp"
                    android:tag="Email Address"
                    android:textColor="#FF777777"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
                    android:textSize="15dip" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/whyLabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:paddingRight="10dip"
                    android:text="@string/why_statement"
                    android:textColor="#2388A5"
                    android:textSize="14dip" />
            </RelativeLayout>

    <!--Other Layouts-->

     </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why you asking a question when you know the answer?

Comment: Just sharing my finding and i am new to posting here.

Comment: this is not how SO works! for sharing use blog/whatever!

Comment: Whatever! Just see the sample and learn it and if u dont like it.. Ignore

Comment: not, if you dont like it, downvote :)

Comment: haha................ :)

Comment: @Selvin http://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/self-answer

Comment: @laalto nice finding ...

Comment: If you self answer question for a tricky problem do it the right ways. (It is not forbidden!) Ask a question that is easy to find for users having the same problem. Post a answer. Accept it, if no other user came up with a better solution.

Comment: There is absolutely no explanation here as to what causes flickering. I have this issue currently on a scrollview. Inside the linear layout I have rows of textviews of which some have a drawable as a background. The flicker appears always at the top of the linear layout and appears to resemble the top of each drawable. Perhaps we guidance on what causes the flicker would help this post have some meaning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sample above in the question, background has been set to color WHITE for email in both emailEditText and emailArea. This is the reason for flickering.
To avoid this flickering just set background to white at one place only.
See the following code :-

```
          <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/stepText"
            android:background="@drawable/textbox_group_border"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/emailArea"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dip" 
                **android:background="@color/color_white"**
                >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="45dip"
                    **android:background="@null"**
                    android:hint="@string/email_address"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                    android:paddingRight="55dp"
                    android:tag="Email Address"
                    android:textColor="#FF777777"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/hint_color"
                    android:textSize="15dip" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/whyLabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:paddingRight="10dip"
                    android:text="@string/why_statement"
                    android:textColor="#2388A5"
                    android:textSize="14dip" />
             </RelativeLayout>

     <!--Other Layouts-->

       </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe i could help you as i understood from your question when you are scrolling the color changed.

just put

```
android:fadescrollbars="false";
```

that's it

hope it helped my friend